# Values don't get saved to the database when fields are wrapped in a container

Tags: 8, entities, ajax

When I wrap a field in a container, the field value doesn't get saved to the database. But if it lives in root, it works properly.

```
public function formElement(
  FieldItemListInterface $items,
  $delta,
  array $element,
  array &$form,
  FormStateInterface $form_state
) {

    $item =& $items[$delta];
    $element += array(
      #type' => 'fieldset',
    );

    /** a bunch of fields **/

    $element['concelhocontainer'] = [
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#attributes' => ['id' => 'concelhocontainer']
    ];

    /** works properly **/
    $element['concelho'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('County'),
      '#default_value' => isset($item->concelho) ? $item->concelho : '',
      '#options' => $this->getConcelhoList()
    ];

  /** does not work
  $element['concelhocontainer']['concelho'] = [
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('County'),
    '#default_value' => isset($item->concelho) ? $item->concelho : '',
    '#options' => $this->getConcelhoList()
  ];
  */
  return $element;
}
```

The problem is that the value of the second input is not saved to the database (I've confirmed it in the database).

Comment: Look up the #parents and #array_parents properties.

Comment: @IvanJaros I did, but the documentation is appaling.

Comment: If you are altering the structure of the form element you should implement \Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase::massageFormValues to fix it into expected format.

Comment: Also see \Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase::formMultipleElements

Comment: @IvanJaros WidgetBase::massageFormValues seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems Drupal adds a `#tree = true` property to the field parent so you need to process the data output by the form youserlf or the form nested elements will be ignored. As @IvanJaros poited out, `WidgetBase::massageFormValues` let's you alter the data.

```
public function massageFormValues(array $values, array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
  for ($i=0; $i < count($values); ++$i) {
    if (isset($values[$i]['concelhocontainer']['concelho'])) {
      $values[$i]['concelho'] = $values[$i]['concelhocontainer']['concelho'];
    }
  }
  return $values;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Life saver. `massageFormValues()` above did the trick. Only that I had to get my values from `$form_state->getUserInput()` and store them in a new `$values = []`